# How to get postion of html tag on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen Coordinates of a element, via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337795/screen-coordinates-of-a-element-via-javascript)

So what I need is simple - find out where on users screen (NOT browser window) top left corner of element is?

Comment: ...and assuming you can get this information... what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the user's *screen*? You can't do that. I'm sure you could code something up like that with a Java applet or similar, but not with JavaScript.

The closest you can get is by getting the position of the browser window using the `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` properties on IE, and the `window.screenLeft`, etc properties on other browsers, then getting the relative offset of the element using the method [described here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) (from Breezer's answer), and adding the coordinates together. Unfortunately, this doesn't account for toolbars or sidebars in the browser, so this is a really *rough estimate*. Don't do this if you need it to be 100% accurate.

Comment: Actually, you can.  See Breezer's answer.

Comment: @El Yobo: He said the user's screen, "NOT browser window". Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you can't figure out the position of the browser window on the screen with JavaScript, so you can't do that.

Comment: @ElYobo - that answer is incorrect, re-read the question - this one is correct.

Comment: If you couldn't, how would [this](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/browser-ball/) work?

Comment: I think you can, window.screen.top gives offset of top edge of client area, for example.

Comment: @Nick, thanks, you're right, I did read the question incorrectly. Unfortunately SO won't let me change my incorrect downvote unless the question is edited... @musicfreak, please make a minor edit to your answer so that I can revert my vote.

Comment: @Paul Dixon: Hmm, Chrome says it's undefined. @passcod: I'm not sure, actually, good question. Although I'm fairly certain that has something to do with the fact that it creates its own windows, which JavaScript has more control over. @El Yobo: I've edited, thanks. :)

Comment: @Paul - this doesn't work cross-browser, for example in Chrome right now `window.screen.top` is `undefined`...@musicfreak is correct in that you can't do this.  The fact that people are downvoting the answer means they didn't read the question at all, or are downvoting because they *assume* you can do this, but don't know how (why haven't *they* posted an answer?)...either way they're wrong.

Comment: @Paul - it appears that there are portability issues with this, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenleft.asp

Comment: It's an interesting question, am digging around but reaching the same conclusion. Seems possible with Firefox, but making something portable looks....hard :)

Comment: Actually, to be clear, that's FF3.6 - it's this property that looks promising there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozInnerScreenX

Answer (score 3):

if you use jquery you can use http://api.jquery.com/position/
other wise you have to use offset read more about it here
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: This finds it in the **browser window**, not the **screen** ...explicitly what the question asked *not* to find.

Comment: If you know the position in the window, you can get the window offset from window.screen, surely?

Comment: @Paul - Nope, even then you don't know the toolbar size, etc. and you can't get the position to begin with.

Comment: But combining that with window.screenX and window.screenY it should get what he needs.

Comment: @AlfonsoML - that gives the upper left corner of the **entire** window, not the page area, which means you still have to account for toolhar height, etc...which you don't know.

Comment: Indeed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504052/determining-position-of-the-browser-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is possible after all; see this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenleft.asp) item (IE) and this other [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenx.asp) (Chrome and FF).  I haven't tested this myself, however.

On browsers *except* Chrome and FF, use window.screenLeft and window.screenTop.
On Chrome and FF use window.screenX and window.screenY (I have tested this in Chrome; it works there).

Comment: Your link clearly shows this *doesn't* work in Chrome or Firefox.  For the second, it's not correct, again this gives the **window** (the entire window, not page area) upper left corner - you still don't know how far between that and the page area.

Comment: @Nick - I have two links.  The first one also says which values to use for FF and Chrome.

Comment: @ElYobo - Please see my comments on the other answer, this isn't correct.  Not my downvote...but this was already discussed in comments on the question already :)

Comment: @Nick, yes, you're right again, didn't think about the other bits inside the screen.  I did mention the portability issues in the comments above - but the Chrome + FF stuff wasn't in there and I had thought that was sufficient... not so, unfortunately.

Comment: Although, if one opened a window using javascript and prevented any window decorations, this *would* be sufficient for that window, yes?

Comment: @El Yobo: Not exactly. What about the title bar? And some browsers (Firefox) let you override the disabling of window decorations, so in those cases it wouldn't work, either. As been said multiple times, you can get a pretty close *guess* but you can never be *exact* about this.

Comment: So it seems; glad to see that your correct answer has eventually floated to the top :)