# Can you get the absolute position of an element on the screen (not in the viewport)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to place an element on an absolute position on the screen, so that it stays in (roughly) the same position, even when the *browser window* is moved (not scrolled). Is such a thing even possible[?](http://i40.photobucket.com/albums/e202/bionicjoe/Animated%20GIFs/yesitis2.gif)

Comment: @WaleedKhan Have you read the question?

Comment: you can use the `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` to calculate the offset

Comment: @Josh Besides you need to [imitate window move event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4319487/1249581).

Comment: See [here][1] it looks a little bit problematic.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337795/screen-coordinates-of-a-element-via-javascript

Comment: @VisioN i dont have the time to write the full code now. i was just giving a hint so somebody can take it from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the most optimized solution, but you could use an interval to check the `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` (as suggested in the comments). Then, when those values change, update the position using the difference from the last position. Something like:

```
function setPosition(el, x, y) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    el.style.left = parseInt(style.left) + x + "px";
    el.style.top = parseInt(style.top) + y + "px";
}

var sX = window.screenX,
    sY = window.screenY,
    box = document.getElementById("box");

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (window.screenX !== sX || window.screenY !== sY) {
        setPosition(box, sX - window.screenX, sY - window.screenY);
        sX = window.screenX;
        sY = window.screenY;
    }
}, 1000/30);
```

Here is an example of [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPkwK/). It's a bit choppy on Chrome.

Comment: Very nice! One thing: maximizing the window seems to throw off the positioning. Any idea if that can be corrected for? I presume it would need to become aware of window resizings?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create a method of handling the resize as well.